# Batch file: i was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

When i run the following command it works fine:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd box') DO @%i
```

But then when i put it inside a batch file i get the error 'i was unexpected at this time'. Inside the batch file the command looks like this:

```
CALL @FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd box') DO @%%i
```

I've tried putting the %i inside quotation marks and using ^ and none of these fixed it. Why is it happening?

Comment: why do you need to `call` the `for` command? It would make more sense to `FOR /f .... DO call %%I`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call` is used to call actual executables such as, batch files, executables or anything that is associated with an executable program. Additionally you can call labels and certain internal cmd commands. So in short, these will work with call:

```
call "D:\My Docs\SomeDoc.docx"
call mybatch.cmd
call ping localhost
call :next
call echo Hello World
```

`for` is an internal command to `cmd.exe` and can therefore not be called. So if you simply do:

```
call for
```

you will get an error stating `for was unexpected` purely becasuse it is expecting something valid to call.

So all you need to do is to remove `call` from you batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('docker-machine env --shell cmd box') do @%%I
```

or still using your (less verbose mode) `@`

```
@for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('docker-machine env --shell cmd box') do @%%I
```

For more reference to any of the commands, simply run them with the `/?` switch for detailed help on each of these internal commands:

```
call /?
for /?
```

Comment: The ***internal*** commands `set` and `echo` ***can*** be pseudo `call`ed to force a second evaluation. You are also missing calling `:labeled` sub routines. Calling external files and executables is possible but useless. You just need to call other batches to be able to return to the caller.

Comment: @LotPings hence the short explanation and the help options at the very end. :)